# Cancelled update statement is preventing drop statement for a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had an update statement on a table with 200M rows in SQL Server, and it had been running over 15 hours and I cancelled the query. Ever since that moment, the performance of the server has significantly dropped. When I tried dropping that table it's not allowed and I believe the table is locked and the changes from the update statement are reverting. I actually don't want that table and need to drop it and what should be my approach. Any help or guidance is much appreciated since I could not come across a proper solution.

I thought of restarting SQL Server and I believe I will get stuck with recover mode and things can get worse.

Comment: `SQL Server` might be still rolling back that `cancelled` `update` statement. `sp_who` to see which process is blocking

Comment: @Squirrel Yes the blk column for the drop statement contains the spid of the update statement, how to overcome this. The only option is to let the update revert before dropping?

Comment: How badly do you want to wreck your db? ;) I think best thing you could do now is remove as much load as possible to help it finish up quicker, though you might also consider it possibly quicker to restore a backup taken just before the update was run. Is it a production system that has acquired new data since the update was started?

Comment: Have you tried the SO DBA site?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes it is a production system, restoring a back up would be time consuming. The only option would be to free up the load and let it finish quicker.

Comment: Hi @PeterSmith what is DBA site

Comment: See [https://dba.stackexchange.com/](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)